# Update table-content between servers

Tags: sql-server, triggers, ssms

My goal is to create a Trigger, which is copying the data from table A on server S1 to Table B on Server S2 if there is an change on table A.
Is there a possibility doing this just in SQL without having linked servers?

I am using SQL Management Studio.

greetings and thank you for your guesses

Comment: Is table A and table B the exact same on both servers?

Comment: @WEI_DBA they have the same structure but different data. In fact table is a combination b  of data from table a & table c (sorry i forgott to mention). a,b and c beeing tables on different servers. but because its a temporary solution i think a workaround with a combination of replications and triggers may do the job if there is no other way. thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you have enterprise edition, you can set up replication.

Comment: That's where I was going next.

Comment: Thank you very much